# I want The input value is not cleared when I popup a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add html code using append, but when adding a second time, the text in the input does not follow the new line :

HTML :

```
    '<form>' +
    '<input type="text" id="newFoldr" name="fname" placeholder=".ex nameFanpage" value="">' +
    '<input type="button" class="cancelButton" id="cancelButton" value="Cancel" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">' +
    '<input type="button" class="submitButton" id="submitButton" value="Create" style="width:142px;margin-left: 5px;">' +
    '</form>' +
```

Javascript :

```
$('.submitButton').click(function () {
    var addFolder = '<div class="_5bm7 _2mk4" role="presentation" style="height: 50px;border:none;"><div class="_5bmf"></div>' +
    '<div class="_1577">' +
    '<div class="ellipsis">' +
    '<div class="_1i5z"><div class="_1i5-">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<span id="namaFolder"></span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    if( document.getElementById("newFoldr").value === '' ){
        swal("Whoops!", "You need to write something!", "info");
    } else {
        $('.columnFolder').append(addFolder);
        var inputan = document.getElementById("newFoldr").value;
        document.getElementById("namaFolder").innerHTML= inputan;
        swal("Success!", "Your folder has been created!", "success");
    }
});
```

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/h1pz43

Comment: Please clarify what you want to ask also tell me what is "newFoldr" in this context.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question, but you mean the Input value does not get cleared when you show the popup the second time?

Comment: Show your complete code please.

Comment: You right, Amit.

Sorry for the bad question, I just learned to program and have not understood how to ask my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not able to clear the input value just add below code in else block

```
document.getElementById("newFoldr").value = "";
```

Complete javascript code is as below

```
$('.submitButton').click(function () {
    var addFolder = '<div class="_5bm7 _2mk4" role="presentation" style="height: 50px;border:none;"><div class="_5bmf"></div>' +
    '<div class="_1577">' +
    '<div class="ellipsis">' +
    '<div class="_1i5z"><div class="_1i5-">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<span></span>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';

    if( document.getElementById("newFoldr").value === '' ){
        swal("Whoops!", "You need to write something!", "info");
    } else {
        $('.columnFolder').append(addFolder);
        var inputan = document.getElementById("newFoldr").value;
        $('.columnFolder div._5bm7._2mk4:last').find('span').text(inputan);
        document.getElementById("newFoldr").value = "";
        swal("Success!", "Your folder has been created!", "success");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want The input value is not cleared when I popup a second time

Comment: So what you want is when i enter a text and click submit for first time it should add new folder. and again when i enter the text and add click it should add new folder below the 1st one...is that what you want?

Comment: Yep...  so, how to create 'New Folder' using Javascript? I dont know what code to use.

Comment: I have edited the answer. please check it now. the main problem was you were appending addFolder div which have a span with id. Now every time you append the div span with same id is created and we cannot have repeated Id in HTMl..javascript will select the 1st element that matches the id. I have added **$('.columnFolder div._5bm7._2mk4:last').find('span').text(inputan);** line

Comment: aw Cool ...  Thank you very much.